# Turtle variable representing memory of other turtles

Tags: netlogo

I have a model in which turtles navigate a graph of nodes (also stored as turtles) and links in discrete increments (using the `move-to` procedure). I would like to create a turtle based variable that allows turtles to remember the number of times they have visited particular nodes in the graph.

e.g.

1. turtle `move-to` a node
2. look up the presence of that node in the desired structure
3. if it exists `set #visits #visits + 1` associated with that node
4. if not include it in the structure and `set #visits 1`

I imagine my options are related to lists or tables - however I am not sure which of these will be most efficient. With regards to tables I don't think the key can be a turtle - perhaps a string derived from its who - but this feels like it may be inefficient.

Two points that are likely pertinent:

- some of the graphs will have a large number of nodes (~5000) , and often some of the turtles will never visit all of them, so it may be sensible to grow the structure on-the-fly to save memory.
- there can also be a relatively large number of agents (~2500)

Any advice, as ever, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables are the more efficient way to go as well as easier codewise, though using agents as keys does not work (much to my surprise). That said, you can just use `who` numbers as keys.

It would look something like:

```
extensions [ table ]
turtles-own [ node-visits ] 

...

to move-to-node [ node ]
  move-to node
  let key [ who ] of node
  let visits ifelse-value (table:has-key? node-visits key) [ table:get node-visits key ] [ 0 ]
  table:put node-visits key (visits + 1)
end
```

tables are efficient in both memory use and lookup speed. You could do this with lists and be efficient in memory use (if you use key value pairs) *or* lookup speed (if you use `who` numbers as indices or something) but not both, unless you basically write your own hash table implementation with lists.

Now, all that aside, you generally should worry about performance problems like these until you are:

1. having performance problems right now
2. know that these things are the source of your performance problems (by profiling either with the timer or with the `profiler` extension)

The real reason I suggest the table extension is because it's the simplest to implement.

Comment: Thanks for this Bryan - looks exactly what I'm looking for. However, when implementing I get the following error message:


`Extension exception: (subnode 149) is not a valid table key (a table key may only be a number, a string, true or false, or a list whose items are valid keys)`


I instantiated the table with `set node-visits table:make`. I'm also running 5.2.1 not 5.3.1 if that makes a difference.

Comment: I opened an issue for the agents-as-keys thing: https://github.com/NetLogo/Table-Extension/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

I realize I am late to the party, and Bryan's answer is perfectly fine, but an alternative solution would be to use a separate breed of links to record the number of visits to a node:

```
breed [ nodes node ]
undirected-link-breed [ edges edge ] ;  node <---> node
breed [ agents an-agent ]
directed-link-breed [ visits visit ] ; agent ----> node
visits-own [ num-visits ]

to setup
  clear-all  
  create-nodes 10 [ create-edges-with n-of (1 + random 2) other nodes ]
  create-agents 10 [ move-to one-of nodes ]
end

to go
  ask agents [
    let destination one-of [ edge-neighbors ] of one-of nodes-here
    move-to destination
    if out-visit-to destination = nobody [ create-visit-to destination ]
    ask out-visit-to destination [ set num-visits num-visits + 1 ]
  ]
end
```

It might not be quite as fast as using the table extension, but it would have the advantage of allowing queries from both sides: you ask an agent how many times it visited which nodes, but you can also ask a node how many times it has been visited by which agents.